# Cannot use jQuery .get() to get html content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, get

I want to get the html content of another page, so i use the following jquery .get() function

```
$.get("chk_vga.aspx", function(data) {
    alert($('#vga').html());
});
```

in the "chk_vga.aspx" page, it only have one value

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="vga">F</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

how can my jquery function get the "F" value?

Comment: Added two options, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the content you need to add it to an element.

```
$.get("chk_vga.aspx", function(data) {
    var foo = jQuery("<div></div>").html(data).find("#vga").html();
    alert(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.load('chk_vga.aspx #vga', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: That will get his entire HTML page I believe. I think he's just trying to get the "F".

Comment: No it won't, the `url` argument for `$.get` includes a selector for the `id=vga`.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the #vga selector. My mistake.

Comment: It's easier as I posted, this will get really just innerHTML of it

Answer (score 1):

Here what you are doing is to `alert()` the `#vga` inner HTML of parent. If you use this code, you will get #vga inner HTML of the #vga div on the remote page.

```
$.get('chk_vga.aspx', function(data) {
    alert(data.match(/id="vga">(.[^\"]*)<\/div>/i)[1]);            
});
```

OR

```
$.get('chk_vga.aspx', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```